# can't get Firebird DDEX .NET provider integration to work with visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, .net-4.0, firebird, firebird2.5

Description: After installing Firebird Client and DDEX for Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0) I am unable to add new connection to firebird from Visual Sutio 2010 (Professional)->Server Explorer->Data Connections->Add Connection.

performed steps:
- installed firebirdclient (NETProvider-2.6.0.msi -> C:\Program Files\FirebirdClient) 
- added assembly (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll) to gac
    proof:

> ```
> C:\Program Files\FirebirdClient>gacutil /i
> ```
>
> firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient.dll
>       Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
>       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> ```
> Assembly successfully added to the cache
> ```

- got DDEX 2.0.5, -> C:\Program Files\FirebirdClient\DDEX205
- added FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.dll to gac (somebody wrote it might help)

> ```
> C:\Program Files\FirebirdClient\DDEX205>gacutil
> ```
>
> /i FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.Data
>       Tools.dll
>       Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
>       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> ```
> Assembly successfully added to the cache
> ```

- edited VS2010 version of FirebirdDDEXProvider32

> @=".NET Framework Data Provider for
>   Firebird"
>   "DisplayName"="Provider_DisplayName,
>   FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.Properties.Resources"
>   "ShortDisplayName"="Provider_ShortDisplayName,FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.Properties.Resources"
>   "Description"="Provider_Description,
>   FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.Properties.Resources"
>   "CodeBase"="C:\Program
>   Files\FirebirdClient\DDEX205\FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.dll"
>   "InvariantName"="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"
>   "Technology"="{77AB9A9D-78B9-4ba7-91AC-873F5338F1D2}"

installed that (the whole file) as well
- in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
in  I added

```
<section name="firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

in  I added

```
  <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c" />
```

I can connect via FbConnection to a firebird db

in Visual Studio 2010 IDE I can server explorer -> Data Connections -> Add Connection and choose Firebird Data Source but I never get any further! As soon as I press a key in any field the windows disapears (or if I choose a language, dialect whatever, windows disapears...).

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OMG

> C:\Program
>   Files\FirebirdClient>gacutil /l
>   Firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient
>   Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly
>   Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. 
>   All rights reserved.
>
> The Global Assembly Cache contains the
>   following assemblies:
>   Firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient,
>   Version=**2.6.0.0**, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyTo ken=**3750abcc3150b00c**,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL
>
> Number of items = 1

- Version is **2.6.0.0** not 4.0.0.0 
  =>

it runs on .NET 4.0 but the assembly version IS 2.6.0.0

After this restart visual studio and it WORKS!

Comment: Glad that worked. Please read the "how to format" box on the editor page. Please.

Comment: If this worked for you, you should mark this as the accepted answer (and win a badge for that)

Comment: Have the same issue but your solution doesn't work for me? (Windows 7 64 bit, VS2010)

Answer (score 2):

> in Visual Studio 2010 IDE I can server explorer -> Data Connections -> Add Connection and choose Firebird Data Source but I never get any further! As soon as I press a key in any field the windows disapears (or if I choose a language, dialect whatever, windows disapears...).

make sure edit the .NET framework file called `Machine.config` at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config`
for windows 7 64 bit also edit `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config`

First you must obtain accurate values to be placed in the Machine.config file, via gacutil:

```
c:\>gacutil -l FirebirdSQL.Data.FirebirdClient
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  FirebirdSQL.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTo
ken=3750abcc3150b00c, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

sample of adding the provider:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
  <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```